# shell variable usage in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am currently having problems with awk usage of shell variables. Here's my problem,
when I run the following:

> awk -F: '$1=="marco" {print $7}' /etc/passwd

everything works fine and dandy. However, I want to be able to pass my $user shell variable instead of "marco", so I try the following (after reading about -v flag):

> awk -F: -v awkvar=$user '$1=="$awkvar" {print $7}' /etc/passwd

and it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotation marks on the shell side, and don't use `$` for awk variables.

```
awk -F: -v awkvar="$user" '$1==awkvar {print $7}' /etc/passwd
```

In `awk`, `$` indicates that it's a positional parameter (i.e. a field number), so as it was, it was looking for field "marco", which reduces to `$0`, the whole line. So it would find any line with only one field.

Comment: Good answer, I didn't know that a string as a field name reduces to 0.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. In awk, a variable is substituted without the `$` sigil. `$` means "the field at position", so `$awkvar` means "the field at position *value of awkvar*". If `awkvar=marco`, then `$awkvar` is the same as `$"marco"`, equivalent to $0.
2. Unlike shell variables, you can't quote awk variables, or else they are treated as strings:

   ```
   sh$ awk -v awkvar=foo 'BEGIN{print "awkvar",awkvar}'
   awkvar foo
   sh$
   ```
3. The standard shell variable containing the username is `$USER`, not `$user`

So in conclusion, what you want is this:

```
awk -F: -v awkvar=$user '$1==awkvar {print $7}' /etc/passwd
```

Or, using [`getent`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent):

```
getent passwd $USER | awk -F: '{print $7}'
```

Comment: It's safer to quote shell variables to protect against whitespace (although you don't expect that in a username). Which brings up another point. Perhaps Marco is using `$user` to hold a username from user input or another source rather than using the `$USER` environment variable. This would be proper to avoid name collision. If the data may be from an "untrusted" source, it could contain anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an `awk` but a shell problem.

This one would work (if the `$user` variable is set in your shell environment).

```
awk -F: '$1=="'"$user"'" {print $7}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: The `-v awkvar=$user` indicates he was trying to set and use the awk variable, so it was indeed an awk problem, not a shell one. But your solution does produce the right output in the end, so I decided to undo my downvote.

Comment: You should use `-v` and not use nested quoting.